# Trying to parse Uri from a string but I get the error permission denial: ACTION_OPEN DOCUMENT

Tags: java, android, android-studio

In my code I saved the Uri I got after choosing an image from the gallery as a string file and then saved it in a database then I passed the value of the database into a constructor of the class note and it uses the method getAddress now I want to parse the Uri back from the generated string but it keeps giving me the ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT error and I need this done before Tuesday.

```
package com.example.bookreviewapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.List;

public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder> {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Note> notes;
    Uri new_image_Uri;

    Adapter(Context context,List<Note> notes){
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.notes = notes;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_views,viewGroup,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        String  title    = notes.get(i).getTitle();
        String genre      = notes.get(i).getGenre();
        String review      = notes.get(i).getReview();
        String address      = notes.get(i).getAddress();

        new_image_Uri = Uri.parse(address);

        viewHolder.nTitle.setText(title);
        viewHolder.nGenre.setText(genre);
        viewHolder.nReview.setText(review);
        viewHolder.nImage.setImageURI(new_image_Uri);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return notes.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView nTitle,nGenre,nReview;
        ImageView nImage;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            nTitle  = itemView.findViewById(R.id.review_ttl_1);
            nGenre  = itemView.findViewById(R.id.review_gnr_1);
            nReview  = itemView.findViewById(R.id.review_text_1);
            nImage  = itemView.findViewById(R.id.review_book_1);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(),ViewReviewActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("Title",notes.get(getAdapterPosition()).getTitle());
                    Log.i("tag", notes.get(getAdapterPosition()).getTitle());
                    v.getContext().startActivity(i);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Edit

This is the stack trace of the error that I've been getting.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.bookreviewapplication, PID: 15056
    java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadStorageProvider from ProcessRecord{e1a41b2 15056:com.example.bookreviewapplication/u0a154} (pid=15056, uid=10154) requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs
        at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:2373)
        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2357)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2340)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2282)
        at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.getContentProvider(IActivityManager.java:5702)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:6813)
        at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:2935)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:2481)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1967)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1921)
        at android.graphics.ImageDecoder$ContentResolverSource.createImageDecoder(ImageDecoder.java:274)
        at android.graphics.ImageDecoder.decodeDrawableImpl(ImageDecoder.java:1758)
        at android.graphics.ImageDecoder.decodeDrawable(ImageDecoder.java:1751)
        at android.widget.ImageView.getDrawableFromUri(ImageView.java:1011)
        at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:980)
        at android.widget.ImageView.setImageURI(ImageView.java:557)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageURI(AppCompatImageView.java:120)
        at com.example.bookreviewapplication.Adapter.onBindViewHolder(Adapter.java:58)
        at com.example.bookreviewapplication.Adapter.onBindViewHolder(Adapter.java:26)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7065)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7107)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6012)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6279)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6118)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6114)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2303)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1627)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4134)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3851)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4404)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1103)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1103)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1855)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1231)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
```

This is my android manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.bookreviewapplication">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.BookReviewApplication">
        <activity android:name=".ProfileActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".ViewReviewActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".AddReviewActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".BookReviewMainActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".LogInActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".SignUpActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This error doesn't come the first time I try to run the program but when I close it and re open the program.

Comment: "it keeps giving me the ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT error" -- what is "it"? Is this a compiler error? If so, what is the specific error message? Or, if this is a runtime error, perhaps you could edit your question and post the complete stack trace.

Comment: It's a runtime error.

Comment: Then, perhaps you could edit your question and post the complete stack trace.

Comment: I've edited the code, this error doesn't come on first run but when I re-open the program.

Comment: https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/08/08/uri-access-lifetime-still-shorter-than-you-might-think.html

Comment: Thanks, this explained a lot.

Comment: @CommonsWare pls what is the best way for me to store an image and then use it in other activities. I tried saving it as an Uri object but that did not work and I tried saving the file name so I can search it up but it did not work either.

Comment: "I tried saving it as an Uri object but that did not work" -- I am having to guess that by "saving" you mean writing the value of the `Uri` out to disk somewhere (e.g., `SharedPreferences`). If you used `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` to get the `Uri` in the first place, and you called `takePersistableUriPermission()` on a `ContentResolver` after getting the `Uri` in `onActivityResult()`, then writing it to disk and using it later should work in general. If that is what you tried, ask a separate Stack Overflow question with a fresh [mcve] showing what you tried and what did not work.

Answer (score 0):

first of all make sure your Manifest file contains the appropriate permissions to do this task like explained here https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files. Simply add this line to your AndroidManifest.xml

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

(inside the manifest block)

Once you get the string to be parsed as Uri check if it is in RFC-2396 compliant format like explained here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri#parse(java.lang.String)

Comment: I've tried this in the manifest file including the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions.

Comment: do you open it as read only or do you try to open it as read-write?